# Thymeleaf: Inserting content of webjar CSS file into style tag

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In some scenarios, inlining a CSS file is preferred over referencing it via URL (e.g. when rendering an all-including HTML page). That CSS file might come from a webjar.

What do I need to make a call like this work:

```
<style th:insert="/webjars/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"></style>
```

This is run in a spring-boot environment, without any webserver.

Comment: I think you should just use <style src="/webjars/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"  type="text/css"></style>

Comment: That's not what I want. I want the content of the bootstrap.css file to be rendered into the style tag. Also, CSS is not referenced this way, but with <link rel="stylesheet" href="..." />

Comment: it's not something that will change. so you can just put it there yourself. but the benefit of linking is the browser can cache it and not dl when it goes to the page again. this way it has to dl everytime.

Comment: In my scenario, linking is not possible. That's why I'm asking on how to inline it. Also, I don't want to copy the file content into my sources. I want it to be inserted from the webjar. Downloading it everytime is a tradeoff I can easily live with here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made it work with a special TemplateResolver. It's logic is similar to Spring's [`WebJarsResourceResolver`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/WebJarsResourceResolver.java), and uses [`WebJarAssetLocator`](https://github.com/webjars/webjars-locator-core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/webjars/WebJarAssetLocator.java).

```
public class WebJarTemplateResolver extends ClassLoaderTemplateResolver {

    private final static String WEBJARS_PREFIX = "/webjars/";

    private final static int WEBJARS_PREFIX_LENGTH = WEBJARS_PREFIX.length();

    private final WebJarAssetLocator webJarAssetLocator = new WebJarAssetLocator();

    @Override
    protected ITemplateResource computeTemplateResource(IEngineConfiguration configuration, String ownerTemplate, String template, String resourceName, String characterEncoding, Map<String, Object> templateResolutionAttributes) {

        resourceName = findWebJarResourcePath(template);
        if (resourceName == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return super.computeTemplateResource(configuration, ownerTemplate, template, resourceName, characterEncoding, templateResolutionAttributes);
    }

    @Nullable
    protected String findWebJarResourcePath(String templateName) {
        if (!templateName.startsWith(WEBJARS_PREFIX)) {
            return null;
        }

        int startOffset = WEBJARS_PREFIX_LENGTH;
        int endOffset = templateName.indexOf('/', startOffset);

        if (endOffset == -1) {
            return null;
        }

        String webjar = templateName.substring(startOffset, endOffset);
        String partialPath = templateName.substring(endOffset + 1);
        return this.webJarAssetLocator.getFullPathExact(webjar, partialPath);
    }
}
```

This is integrated into the application with this configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfiguration {

    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    public ThymeleafConfiguration(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        this.templateEngine = templateEngine;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void enableWebjarTemplates() {
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(new WebJarTemplateResolver());
    }
}
```